# why the date on parameter has been updated

Tags: java, calendar

I really can't understand this problem.

I have this function

```
public Timestamp getRealDateInvoice(Timestamp dateInvoiced) {

  Timestamp date = dateInvoiced;        
  if (INVOICEFREQUENCY_Monthly.equals(getInvoiceFrequency())
                    || INVOICEFREQUENCY_TwiceMonthly.equals(getInvoiceFrequency())) {
    Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    aCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); // add -1 month to current month
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1); // set DATE to 1, so first date of previous month
    aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, aCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); // set actual maximum date of the previous month
    date.setTime(aCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
  }
```

i will execute it with this value : `getRealDateInvoice('09/11/2015')`
Result

`date = 31/10/2015` (this is Ok).

`dateInvoiced = 31/10/2015` (this is not Ok).

Question :
why the variable `dateInvoiced` has been **updated** too
Thanks.

Comment: `Timestamp date = dateInvoiced;` so both refer to the same instance.

Comment: any idea to fix that ?

Comment: You should create a new Timestamp: `new java.sql.Timestamp(aCalendar.getTimeInMillis())`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Timestamp object, as it takes long type as parameter, do it like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("09/11/2015");
long time = date.getTime();
new Timestamp(time);
```